# Socket Receiving Data as null

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to receive data from an app connected to my server but it is sending the data as null?

```
//Receive Data
int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
string ReserveText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
//Write to Console if no error appears
Console.WriteLine("Message received from client: " + ReserveText);
```

It is currently printing **Message received from client:** and it is ment to print the 'ReserveText' after it but the reserve test is obviously empty? The above code is my server code and below I have shared the full void and the code in the client.

Full Void:

```
public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
    string clientIP = socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
    try
    {
        //Receive Data
        int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
        byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
        string ReserveText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
        //Write to Console if no error appears
        Console.WriteLine("Message received from client: " + ReserveText);

        string ResponceText = "Testing Response";
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ResponceText);
        //socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
        SendAsync(socket, data, 0, data.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent to client: " + ResponceText);

        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
            socket);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected");
        //TODO: DISPOSE THE SOCKET/SESSION FROM _clients
    }
}
```

Here is the method on the client side SENDING to the server

```
public static string SendMessageAndReturnResponse(string req)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
    _clientSocket.Send(buffer);

    byte[] receivedBuf = new byte[1024];
    int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuf);
    byte[] data = new byte[rec];
    Array.Copy(receivedBuf, data, rec);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
}
```

Comment: It's a very bad practice to catch exceptions and ignore them. In particular, you will never know which exception you received. I recommend you either not catch any exceptions, or else catch something specific like SocketException. In your `catch` block, be sure to look at the value of [`ex.SocketErrorCode'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.socketerrorcode.aspx) to be sure of which problem just happened.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious wrong. So whatever the problem is, it's either in some code you didn't share, or something else entirely. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. In the meantime, I will mention that you don't need to copy the received data to a new buffer; just use the `GetString()` method overload that allows you to pass the start index and length for the input bytes (so that you can use `_buffer` directly).

Comment: Where is your begin receive event?  It is normal to receive data in the event with the byte count = 0.  You must ignore any receive events with no data.  You are also using ASCII encoding which will remove non printable characters.  You may need to use UTF8 encoding instead.